# Getting the correct axes label in imshow in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am using the following code to generate some contour plots,

```
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp,arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def z_func(x,y):
    func = 3.0*(1.0 - x)**2*np.exp(-x**2 - (y+1.0)**2) - 10.0*(x/5.0 - x**3 - y**5)*np.exp(-x**2 - y**2) - 0.33*np.exp(-(x + 1.0)**2 - y**2)
    return func


x = arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1)
y = arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y) # grid of point
Z = z_func(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
im = imshow(Z,cmap=cm.RdBu) # drawing the function
# adding the Contour lines with labels
cset = contour(Z,arange(-1,1.5,0.2),linewidths=2,cmap=cm.Set2)
clabel(cset,inline=True,fmt='%1.1f',fontsize=10)
colorbar(im) # adding the colobar on the right
# latex fashion title
title('peaks function')
show()
```

I stole it from somehwere on StackExchange. I am having a difficult time simply getting the x and y axes to display the correct domains, [-4,4]. There are a number of solutions already posted that do not work for me such as [Change values on matplotlib imshow() graph axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696122/change-values-on-matplotlib-imshow-graph-axis) and [correcting the axes using imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480568/correcting-the-axes-using-imshow) but neither keep the image the way it is and relabels the axes. Help!!!

Comment: This code is not working. Do you just want to set axises limits for imshow?

Comment: The code works for me. I forgot my imports...let me put in now. I want the axes to reflect the actual bounds for my input variables, [-4,4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, you have to set limits in both functions `contour` and `imshow` as I did:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # grid of point
Z = X**2. * np.sin(Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
im = plt.imshow(Z,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, extent=(-4,4,-4,4)) # drawing the function
# adding the Contour lines with labels
cset = plt.contour(Z,np.arange(-1,1.5,0.2),linewidths=2,cmap=plt.cm.Set2, extent=(-4,4,-4,4))
plt.clabel(cset,inline=True,fmt='%1.1f',fontsize=10)
plt.colorbar(im) # adding the colobar on the right
# latex fashion title
plt.title('peaks function')
plt.show()
```

[image]

There is a problem in your code: `Z` have to be a 2d array but `z_fun_optimization(x)` get only one argument.

Comment: Cutting and pasting error. My fault :-0. Updated code is there. This did it though! I was forgetting to put in the `extent` argument in the contour argument as well. Thanks!